# Combine two php scripts/functions

Tags: php

Good morning, everyone...

*Newbie alert*

I have the following script which displays images from a folder with PHP:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/homes/forge-weir-view/galleries/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="Slideshow Image">';
    }
?>
```

Which works perfect! However, I'd like to also combine the an item alias into the 'glob' path. This is the item alias:

```
<?php echo $this->_item->alias; ?>
```

And this is what I have so far without any success:

```
$files = glob("images/homes/forge-weir-view/galleries/"."$item->alias;"."*.*");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: `$this->_item->alias` or `$item->alias` ? Does it end with a slash? `"."$item->alias;"."` can be written as `".$item->alias."`

Comment: The semicolon after `$item->alias` looks redundant. Also you don't need the quotes over `$item->alias` (see previous comment of @kerbholz)

Comment: Thanks for you help on this. I now have it working